# How to pass function pointer to function in c?

Tags: c

Can anybody please guide me how to pass a function pointer to a function as argument one with second argument being int*? The function then calls a function whose pointer is passed as first argument by passing the
second argument to it.

Comment: Don't describe code - show it.

Comment: @Armali: A person cannot show code they do not have and do not know how to write.

Comment: He wrote _The function then calls a function …_ as if that function would exist.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Showing code with some placeholders still helps, instead of trying to figure out what the OP means. You can still write pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Can give you this example

```c
int plus_one(int nb)
{
    return nb + 1;
}

int call_func(int (*func)(int), int *param)
{
    return (*func)((*param));
}
```

I Think what you want is the call_func functions, so the important is to pass as first paramaeter something with this format :
`return_type (*name_you_give_to_the_function)(parameter_type1, parameter_type2, ...) //parentheses to indicates that is a function`

So with that you can make function calling any type of function

to call your call function , just write the name of your function as first parameter :

Exemple link to the previous one

```c
int main(void)
{
    int nb = 3;
    int res = call_func(plus_one, &nb);
    printf("res: %d\n", res);
}
```

Comment: specify type completelly your callback int (*func)(int) to prevent missuse

Answer (score 0):

A function with an `int *` parameter is declared as `void FunctionName(int *)`. (You can use something other than `void` for the return type.)

Then a pointer to such a function is declared as `void (*PointerName)(int *)`.

So to declare a function with a parameter of this type, we use that declaration for the parameter: `void CallingFunctionName(void (*PointerName)(int *), int *IntegerName)`.

Here is an example:

```
void CallingFunction(void (*PointerToFunction)(int *), int *Q)
{
    PointerToFunction(Q);  // Call the function and pass it Q.
}
```

### Notes

Note that to call a function by a pointer, you just have to write a function call using the pointer, `PointerToFunction(Q)`. You do not have to use `*` to make the pointer into a function, as in `(*PointerToFunction)(Q)`. All function calls are actually done through pointers, and, when you use a function name in a function call, it is automatically converted to a pointer anyway. So, when you already have a pointer, just use it.

Similarly, because you can only pass a pointer to a function as a parameter, not an actual function, if you use a function declaration for a parameter, it will be automatically adjusted to be a pointer to a function. This means we can change the example to:

```
void CallingFunction(void PointerToFunction(int *), int *Q)
{
    PointerToFunction(Q);
}
```